# How do I override the defaultValues in useForm and maintain the isDirty function?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I have a situation where I need to call my DB to obtain some default values. But in the off-chance the data does not exist, I will set some default values in my `useForm`. Basically, this means that the `defaultValues` declared in `useForm` is a fallback value if I fail to obtain the default values from the DB.

From what Im understanding, according to the [documentation](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform) with regards to `useForm`,

> The defaultValues for inputs are used as the initial value when a component is first rendered, before a user interacts with it.

Or basically, the `useForm` is one of the first things defined when the page is loaded.

So, unless I can call my DB *before* `useForm` is loaded, Im a little stuck on this.

I've read that each `Controller` field can have something called `defaultValue` which sounds like the solution, but the documentation mentioned a caveat of

> If both defaultValue and defaultValues are set, the **value from defaultValues will be used**.

I considered `setValues` but I want to use the `isDirty` function, which allows field validation and the value used to check whether the form is dirty is based on the `useForm defaultValues`. Thus, if I were to use `setValues`, the form would be declared dirty, which is something I do not want.

TL;DR this is what I want:

This is my initial value(the fallback value, result A).

```
const { formState: { isDirty }, } = useForm(
        {defaultValues:{
            userID: "",
            userName: "",
            userClass: "administrator",
        }}
    );
```

What I want to do is to make a DB call and replace the data, so that it would now look something like this(result B) if the call is successful(if fail, it will remain as result A).

```
const { formState: { isDirty }, } = useForm(
        {defaultValues:{
            userID: "1",
            userName: "user",
            userClass: "administrator",
        }}
    );
```

Please note that the DB call will replace only the `userID` and `userName` default values, the default value for `userClass` will be maintained.

So, the flow is as such:

Case 1: render form -> result A -> DB call -> success -> result B

Case 2: render form -> result A -> DB call -> fail/no data -> result A

So, unless I actually key in an input that is different from the default values of either results depending on the case, both Case 1 and Case 2 should return `isDirty==false` when I check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For `react-hook-form@7.22.0` and newer**

I think you want to use [`reset`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/reset) here in combination with `useEffect` to trigger it when your DB call has finished. You can additionally set some config as the second argument to `reset`, for example affecting the `isDirty` state in your case.

Although your answer works there is no need to use `getValues` here, as `reset` will only override the fields which you are passing to `reset`. Your linked answer is for an older version of RHF, where this was necessary.

Also if you're not adding a field dynamically on runtime then you can just pass the whole object you get from your DB call to `reset` and set the `shouldUnregister` to `true` in your `useForm` config. This way props from your `result` object which haven't got a corresponding form field will get ignored.

```js
export default function Form() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, reset, formState } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      userID: "",
      userName: "",
      userClass: "administrator"
    },
    shouldUnregister: true
  });

  console.log(formState.isDirty);

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  const onReset = async () => {
    const result = await Promise.resolve({
      userID: "123",
      userName: "Brian Wilson",
      otherField: "bla"
    });

    reset(result);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    onReset();
  }, []);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <label>User ID</label>
      <input type="text" {...register("userID")} />

      <label>User Name</label>
      <input type="text" {...register("userName")} />

      <label>User Class</label>
      <input type="text" {...register("userClass")} />

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Here is a Sandbox demonstrating the explanation above:

[image: Edit react-hook-form-reset-v7 (forked)]

**For older versions**

Just merge your `defaultValues` or field values via `getValues` with the result of your DB call.

```js
export default function Form() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    formState,
    getValues,
    control
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      userID: "",
      userName: "",
      userClass: "administrator"
    },
    shouldUnregister: true
  });

  console.log(formState.isDirty);

  const onSubmit = (data, e) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  const onReset = async () => {
    const result = await delay();

    reset({ ...getValues(), ...result });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    onReset();
  }, []);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <label>User ID</label>
      <input type="text" {...register("userID")} />

      <label>User Name</label>
      <input type="text" {...register("userName")} />

      <label>User Class</label>
      <Controller
        name="userClass"
        control={control}
        render={({ field }) => <input type="text" {...field} />}
      />

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-hook-form-reset-v7 (forked)]

Comment: This looks viable. Will have to try it out. But reading the docs, one question arise: does it override all the ```defaultValues``` result or can I do it for a specific field? Cause I need to do it for a specific field. I'll further clarify it in the main post.

Comment: @Erik please see my updated answer. Your answer is kind of misleading and covers an older version for RHF. Besides that it has a flaw by using `getValues`.

Comment: " reset will only override the fields which you are passing to reset " - before I wrote my answer, I actually tried doing something similar to what you did based on your original answer: only parse in the fields I wanted to reset. What happened was that every other field except the ones I parsed in became ```""```. What I did was the same as my answer minus the ```getValues()``` function(so it's basically ```reset({...dataArray})``` ) . AFAIK, I should be using specifically RHF 7.20.2, so maybe I missed something.

Comment: Thx for your input, i checked it and it is only possible since `react-hook-form@7.22.0` to use `reset` as i wrote in my original answer. I updated my answer to provide solutions for both scenarios. Nonetheless i think you can omit the check for `result`in your `useEffect` - check my answer or sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

I went and further googled the issues I had with [@knoefel's original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/70607261/1), and I came across [this](https://spectrum.chat/react-hook-form/help/reset-only-one-field%7E3b9427eb-bfd2-4244-8c5e-00874085fd4c)

Thus, the solution I came up with, based on a combination with @knoefel's answer and the answer in the link:

```
useEffect(async () => {

    let dataArray={};

    let result= fetch('my-db-call');
    if(result) {
       dataArray['userID']=result.userID
       dataArray['userName']=result.userName
    }

    reset({...getValues(), ...dataArray})
  }, [])
```

Apparently, what happens is that the the `reset` function will first set the values, result A, using `...getValues()` and any subsequent data after will replace the previously set values only if it exist. (eg. if my `dataArray` object lacks the `userID` key, it **will not replace** the `userID` default with the new default. ).

Only after both `getValues` and `dataArray` is set then will it reset the default values.

As far as I can tell, this is more or less incline with what I need and should give me result B.